# Why can't Eclipse find regex on Mac OSX?

Tags: regex, eclipse, c++11, osx-mountain-lion

I'm using Eclipse Juno on OSX Mountain Lion and wanted to use std::regex, which I know is a C++11 only feature.  When I `#include <regex>` the IDE says it doesn't exist.  Maybe it's good to note that the header regex.h is present /usr/include/, though I see no specific library for it in /usr/lib/ or /usr/local/lib/, though I'm not aware if that's relevant.  This is just a side project for fun so I'm not using a customized build system, just a regular C++ project in Eclipse.

I'm not real experienced when it comes to modifying a build process (other than setting include paths, libraries, etc.), especially when an IDE like Eclipse is driving it, but my assumption is that the compiler and linker (GCC G++) isn't configured for C++11, though I've tried various recommendations from SO and the Eclipse forums, like adding -std=c++11, but I just keep seeing output saying that they're unrecognized arguments.

I'm sure someone out there has dealt with this issue.  Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did my answer help you, I had the same problem for a while

Answer (score 2):

On mac you have to use the flag:
`-stdlib=libc++`
and even then I believe generally only clang is updated enough(so use clang instead of gcc), if you've just been using the Xcode updates. You should also make sure that your Xcode command line tools are updated, because I would guess that is the compiler eclipse is using.

Comment: Hi I apologize for not checking your answer sooner.  I'm not a regular user of XCode, but it is what I originally used to install gcc for building other projects.  I've checked and command line tools are up-to-date as well.  As for using clang instead of gcc, I'm not real sure how to change that in Eclipse (the toolchain editor doesn't show clang).  Since clang is gcc compatible, I was under the assumption that Eclipse thinks it's using gcc instead of clang somehow.  I've gotten around some need for regex using substrings for now.  But in the future, this would be helpful.

Comment: @JoeyCarson just remember that gcc's regex implementation doesnt even work if u have it updated, so if u cant figure out how to use clang the regexes wont work

Comment: I noticed that my gcc installation in /usr/bin is indeed gcc 4.2, which according to documentation doesn't support cpp 11 or even the experimental support.  I installed gcc 4.7 using brew, but now it appears I have two gcc installations.